# Import Large CSV File to SQL Server Line by Line

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have been trying to load a large a CSV file into my SQL Server using C# through an SSIS script task and it works for files with about 600,000 records or so.  But we have one file which is around 1,000,000 records and it is causing my server to crawl to a halt and CPU to spike.  My problem is I am loading this into memory and not running line by line inserts which would work quickly.  I tried using StreamWriter.ReadLine as well as System.IO.File.ReadAllLines but both times it is loading all into memory then inserting.  I then changed it to try to load line by line but in the below code, it inserts the first line, then moves to the next and unfortunately inserts the first and second, then first, second, third, and so on.  I'm not sure where my logic is wrong where it clears the first line out and   Can someone help with the below code?

```
            System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> ReadAsLines(string filename)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(sodFileName))
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                yield return reader.ReadLine();
            }

            {
                var reader = ReadAsLines(sodFileName);
                var data = new DataTable();

                //Get column headers
                var headers = reader.First().Split(',');
                foreach (var header in headers)
                    data.Columns.Add(header);

                //Get records
                var records = reader.Skip(1);
                    foreach (var record in records)
                    data.Rows.Add(record.Split(','));

                //Load records into table
                var sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(Conn);
                sqlBulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "dbo.sodFileName";
                sqlBulk.WriteToServer(data);
             }
```

Thanks!

EDIT - I also am trying to run the following using ReadLines after researching but am getting a compiler error where I have lines[0].Split(',');

Compiler Error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'type'

Code:

```
                var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(sodFileName);
                if (lines.Count() == 0) return;
                var columns = lines[0].Split(',');
                var table = new DataTable();
                foreach (var c in columns)
                    table.Columns.Add(c);
                for (int i = 1; i < lines.Count() - 1; i++)
                    table.Rows.Add(lines[i].Split(','));
                var sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(Conn);
                sqlBulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "dbo.sodFileName";
                sqlBulk.WriteToServer(table);
```

Would this be a better way and would anyone know how to fix that error?

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code, I would suggest testing your logic with a small file first. ex, with 10 rows. try to debug it., and verify the count of rows in-memory table at the end matches your source file.

Comment: Thanks, I did that and it works with a small file with no issue.  What I see when I debug is I get to the line where I commented //Load records into table and it loops back up to the top and then gets the next row, and so on.  Is there a way to insert after the line is read, then clear out the row in memory then loop back up and read the next, and so on?

Comment: why don't you use flatfilesource? This component will do the job automatically. It loads the records in batches and puts them in the data flow.

Comment: I think that you can just adjust the batch size to fix your problem....  sqlBulk.BatchSize = 10000;

Comment: memory for 1M rows should not be an issue. if it is then consider getting a free EC2 instance from AWS.

Comment: @KeithL Hi Keith, so I should put sqlBulk.BatchSize = 10000 just after sqlBulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 0 ?

Comment: @MostafaNZ I usually do that but the problem here is there's 30 or so files and the file names are dynamic and follow no pattern - so even using a wildcard is more of a headache.

Comment: @KenBalestrieri anywhere before .WriteToServer() and after var sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(Conn);

Comment: if you really want to process line by line then you need to move away from sqlBulkCopy and process using a stream.ReadLine and a sql insert in a while() loop, but the bulk copy is usually much more efficient

Comment: Save them in a variable in the same way you get the file names now. In the flat file connection properties, dynamically create the connection string using expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting the batch size to 10000.  If the large transaction is an issue or log growth is slow, consider using the UseInternalTransaction option if it's okay to import some batches and skip those that have issues.

*"You can explicitly specify the UseInternalTransaction option in the SqlBulkCopy class constructor to explicitly cause a bulk copy operation to execute in its own transaction, causing each batch of the bulk copy operation to execute within a separate transaction."*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.batchsize?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/transaction-and-bulk-copy-operations

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution,

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/685310/Simple-and-Fast-CSV-Library-in-Csharp

This is memory efficient solution, I was able to import .csv files with millions of record.